calculation of date, landing on a workday, don't count holidays
I have a trial date of April 10, 2026.  I need 84 days prior to the trial date and I want it land on a workingday and don't count holidays2026 (range is set out), if any.
=if(WORKDAY.INTL(trial-84),1,1,Holidays2026)
I get the "too few arguments" error but I don't know what needs changing.  It really shouldn't be this hard.

I think what you may want is:
=WORKDAY.INTL(Trial-85,1,1,Holidays2026)

Note that we subtract 85 days and then add back one workday to ensure the result does not fall on a weekend or holiday.

I guess the past date should be sought.

I think you need this:
=WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(2026,4,10),-84,1,Holidays2026).
It is counting backward from DATE(2026,4,10), skipping Holidays2026 and weekends.
To verify, you can use NETWORKDAYS.INTL to check whether the number of work days between this WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(2026,4,10),-84) and DATE(2026,4,10) (both inclusive) is 85, like below:
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(2026,4,10),-84,1,),DATE(2026,4,10),1,)
